# Node sass directory not found

Tags: npm

Trying to run `npm watch` and got the above-mentioned error.

[image: error I got while running npm watch]

Please, how can I resolve such an issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have not already install `node-sass` then install once.

```
npm install node-sass --no-bin-links
```

Or, try rebuilding `node-sass`, with this

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```